# aws cdk - manage the same resource (dynamoDB) from two different stack?

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a scenario where my stack creates dynamodb and other resources.
The resource name is controlled by an input parameter except the dynamodb must be the same one.

if I run the cdk deploy --context name=a, then it success.
if I run the cdk deploy again, with: cdk deploy --context name=b, then it fails because the dynamodb is already created.

Is there a way to manage the same dynamdb with my use case? or what is the best way to improve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create dynamodb once, but the rest of the stack multiple times. I would just separate the dynamodb in a separate stack, and add the stack as a dependency for the current stack. That way, you could create the current stack with as many parameters as you want, without disturbing the dynamodb.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you point me how to add dependency? Thanks.

Comment: You could do something like:
`const dynamoStack = new Stack(app, 'stackname', props); const otherStack = new Stack(app, 'stack2name', props); otherStack.addDependency(dynamoStack);`